# How can i select a row on mouseover in extjs?

Tags: extjs

how can i select a row on mouseover in extjs 3.2?
Or 
How can i get values of row on mouseover.

This is my sample code

```
grid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect', function(sm, rowIdx, r) 
{
 alert(r.get('name'));                                                              
});
```

Thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
grid.on('mouseover',function(e,t){

  var row = this.getView().findRowIndex(t);
  var rec = this.store.getAt(row);
  console.log(rec.get("name"));

});
```